# Firebase security rules for .indexOn : unique uid in iOS/Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security

I've seen several questions about placing specific security rules in Firebase.  I've figured out how to do this in those cases.  Now I'm saving information by authData.uid and getting this info....

```
[Firebase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891" at /UserVideo to your security rules for better performance
```

How can I add such security rules for unique keys and how?? Here is my query...

```
let videoRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("UserVideo")
        videoRef.queryOrderedByChild("\(currentUser)").queryLimitedToFirst(1)
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
                if snapshot != nil
```

Any insight is welcome!!

*** UPDATE ***

Yeah.  I forgot to add that currentUser is...

```
let currentUser = ref.authData.uid
```

And the query actually gives back relevant information.  It just also includes the specified warning.  Will try the second answer a few times and update this post if it works.  If anyone else has any ideas please post.

Comment: This sounds like a query that will progressively start using more time. `videoRef.queryOrderedByChild("\(currentUser)").queryLimitedToFirst(1)`. If you want to store videos-per-user, store them as `/UserVideo/$uid/$videoid`. Your query then becomes direct-access `videoRef.childByAppendingPath("\(currentUser)")` and performance won't depend on the number of users.

Comment: Aside from the advice above, it's difficult to give an answer without seeing a snippet of the relevant JSON (as text please, no screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Security & Rules Quickstart](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj98pP1s6bLAhUS3WMKHUn9D6YQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.firebase.com%2Fdocs%2Fsecurity%2Fquickstart.html&usg=AFQjCNEg619F2_CyCh0yV-fMSXICFAxSgg&sig2=RNECmP77l8DujtK6hY8CwA&bvm=bv.115339255,d.cGc)

> Security and Firebase Rules are used to determine who has read and write access to your database as well to ensure the structure of that data. They are found in the Security tab of your App Dashboard. They come in three flavors: `.write`, `.read`, and `.validate`.

IN answer to your question, add security rules for unique keys by using the `validate` and `write` together.

An example would be:

```
{
"rules": {
"foo": {
  // /foo is readable by the world
  ".read": true,
  // /foo is writable by the world
  ".write": true,
  // data written to /foo must be a string less than 100 characters
  ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
}
    }
       }
```

Does this help?